# How to concatenate fields from two standard objects?

Tags: apex

I've create a function that pulls Id to a set, and a Map to contact that pulls id and in the SOQL statement compare the whoId from Task to Contact.ID then concatenate(Task.subject, Task.Type, Contact.Name) 3 fields to one custom field. I'm not sure how to proceed from here?

```
 public void ListOfTaskIds(list<Task> TaskEventList) {
        Set<ID> whoIdSet = new Set<ID>();
        for(Task e: TaskEventList){
            if(e.whoId != null){
                whoIdSet.add(e.WhoId);
            }
        }
        System.Debug('>>>>>>> the value of:' + whoIdSet);
        Map<ID, Contact> contactMap = new Map<ID, Contact>([select id, name from contact where id in :whoIdSet]);

    }
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by word "slandered" in title.  Possibly a typo?

Comment: changed title obo OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a "slandered" object. I'll assume you meant to say "Standard" object.

I don't know which sobject your custom field belongs to either. So I'll assume it's in the Task sobject (ie., `Task.Your_Custom_Field__c`).

I also don't understand your description of the code. But from reading it, I'll assume you're asking the community how to concatenate `Task.Subject`, `Task.Type`, and `Contact.Name` now that you've compiled your `WhoId`'s and have a map of Contacts.

Here's the next block of code that I think you're looking for:

```
// Concatenate to Task.Your_Custom_Field__c
for (Task e : TaskEventList) {
    Contact c = contactMap.get(e.whoId);

    if (c != null) { 
        e.your_custom_field__c = e.subject + ' ' + e.type + ' ' + c.name;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! that works. and yes i meant "Standard" :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for concatenating more than one Id.

```
String matrixId = '' + Account.Id + Contact.Id;
```

or

```
String matrixId = String.valueof(Account.Id) + String.valueof(Contact.Id)
```